# Best way to watch for insert in a SQL Server table

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, websocket

**Context**

When new data is inserted into a particular table, I want to notify the concerned user in real time.

**Current setup**

I have setup a laravel application in php with a websocket server.
Currently, I am looking for data in the table throught an artisan command and dispatching the event which is correctly received by the client trought the websocket.

```php
public function handle()
    {
        $exports = DB::connection('dialer_ico')->table('Export')
        ->select('*')
        ->whereNotNull('FRoute')
        ->get();

        foreach($exports as $export) {
            DialerCallExportedEvent::dispatch($export->responsable, $export->FRoute);
        }
    }
```

This is working fine, however, what I would like to achieve is as soon as there is an insert in the table, the event is dispatched instead of having to run this artisan command every n seconds with the scheduler.

What is the correct way to do this with SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSocket listener for Microsoft SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566910/websocket-listener-for-microsoft-sql-database)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to achieve this: events or observers.

1. If you just need few listeners, you can directly make use of the model [events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events)
2. If you are listening for many model events, you can use [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)

Both cases work over the Model instance, therefore it doesn't matter what DB engine are you using.
The broadcasting events should be dispatched within the lifecycle events.

EDIT:
Since you need to trigger events when something happens out of the box in the DB, I would try by extending the `TransactionCommitted` DB event.

Add a listener in your `EventServiceProvider.php` listening to the `TransactionCommitted` DB event

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionCommitted;

/**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

    Event::listen(function (TransactionCommitted $event) {
        // Dispatch your DialerCallExportedEvent here
    });
}
```

Take a look at Laravel [events docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#manually-registering-events) and [Laravel API](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Events/TransactionCommitted.php)

Comment: I was not precise enough, I am not creating model on my own, they are created by a thrid-party service, therefore I cannot make use of model event/observer.

Comment: I've updated my answer. FYI I never did it, but it may point you in the right way

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. However, since the table I want to watch is not controlled by the laravel application, I cannot make use of the event api.
My researchs so far point me to either a trigger or a stored clr procedure that would call an api route in my laravel app to notify that an insert occured, then in the laravel app, i would dispatch my event over websockets.